# How to get the center coordinate on react-native map?

Tags: ios, dictionary, react-native

I am using react-native. How to I get the center coordinate on iOS map?

Answer (score 15):

From: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/mapview.html#content

> region {latitude: number, longitude: number, latitudeDelta: number,
>   longitudeDelta: number}
>
> The region to be displayed by the map.
>
> The region is defined by the center coordinates and the span of
>   coordinates to display.

You can thus get the centre coordinates using your map's `region` attribute, using something like

```
getCoordinates(region) {
    return [{
      longitude: region.longitude,
      latitude: region.latitude,
    }];
},
```

If you need a global variable to pass to `getCoordinates`, you can use a global variable that changes with a new value set on various state changes like `onRegionChange`.

Comment: I'm glad! Please upvote/mark as correct if you can (that's my first answer - happy to be finally contributing).

Comment: You have to listen to onRegionChangeComplete to get the region.